# Magical mail delivery method

Tags: society, mythical-creatures

Let's say there is a medieval fantasy type world with no human magic, but with magical creatures that lack intelligence (ex. Drakes not Dragons, Minotaurs not Centaurs).  One of these creatures is like a lanky, but small hound that can run up to 30ish mph (48ish km per hour) and have a magical ability that allows them to locate any human.  This animal has been domesticated for a mail delivery system.  All a person needs is the name of the person and to attach the letter, the hound will then locate the person and deliver the letter, then return to its owner for reward.

My question is: Would this kind of communication/delivery system have a different impact on society than any of the existing communications/delivery systems that we have in the modern real world? Specifically, this is not a broadcast technology, it carries physical matter, and it is decentralized, aspects that make it unique from technology today. Are these significant deviations or would it just be a shortcut to a fast and accurate mail carrier?

Comment: Questions in form of "this is one change, how does it affect *everything*?" are often closed as too broad. And there is a reason to that, I've read books where story was based on one change...

Comment: @molot - the OP specifically asks if this sort of communication's system will speed up technological advancement in general, not to list impacted fields, and go into any specific detail, so I think the question is within scope.

Comment: @SRM  I actually think that the question is broader now than it was previously.  It's changed from impact on technical advancement to impact on society.  This edit takes us farther away from a good question, not closer.

Comment: The original asked about society. This version asks for ways in which we would diverge from current. By having current as a basis, we can focus on the specifics of the divergence as opposed to the open-ended "what would society look like if given this thing".   Regardless, I contend there's a good question to answer here... I tried to elucidate it... I may have failed, but I think it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects would be significant, however, you have to consider the other factors which affected technological development historically.

Communications have always been a major weak point of medieval societies. This system will allow ideas to be spread and propagated much faster than would have been possible for hundreds of years. This will have huge military and political implications.

However, the major factor dominating technological development was not necessarily communication, it was the struggle to survive, and human rights.

When you're focused solely on survival (farming, keeping predators at bay, keeping your lord and master happy), you have precious little time or resources to innovate.

The notable exception is weapons and engines of war, the development of which was sponsored and encouraged by nobles with the obvious purpose of deposing other nobles (or monarchs). Other factions, such as guilds, might also develop some innovative way of making money, and as such, their inventions were often closely guarded secrets. Consider that the Chinese held on to the secret of silk manufacture for a *very* long time.

However, other development was not really encouraged or sponsored. Monks, who lived in a much more secure environment (a monastery), and received resources from the faithful are actually some of the earliest scientists of Europe.

And so, facilitated communications of the type you describe would be quite useful, however their impact on the overall development of mankind will not be as large as you would imagine. For one thing, these hounds probably have a limited range they can travel, and as such, long distance communications will not necessarily be significantly facilitated, and for another, the existence of a mediocre method of local communications might serve as a "safeguard" against someone considering that a *better* method of communication - such as the telephone - is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would have minimal effect, as (at least in times of peace) getting messages through has rarely been a problem in civilized history. This hound would be better than just "giving the letter to someone traveling in the right direction" but not much better than an organized postal service.
This hound is still going to have trouble with crossing big bodies of water without a boat, and while 30 miles an hour is fast, it's only delivering to one person at a time, and within a limited range.

The areas that it would have a big effect are in the financial arena. Having to wait a few hours to see how the orange harvest did instead of a few days would be a big advantage.

If you want some examples from our history, [look at the effects that invention of the telegram had](https://www.reference.com/history/did-telegraph-change-society-948169aed49d514b), as that's a somewhat similar example to these hounds.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Hedwig/owls in the HP series... I think you could return to messenger pigeons (which existed and were in use over 2000 years ago ) and simply add the twist that they could do more than fly 'home'. To my way of thinking, this would not have to impact the society more than any letter system, excepting speed of delivery.
During WWII my parents could not communicate frequently. Mum waited for weeks for letter and just hoped that she would not get a telegram. The impact was in the worry, not in the day-to-day life of not getting news.

http://www.pigeoncontrolresourcecentre.org/html/the-pigeon-in-history.html

Comment: I know you want it to be a hound, but regardless, it is the same sort of idea.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the possibility of coordination between separate military forces.  Or the ability to react to military incursion.  For example, with this, Rome would have had days to respond to Julius Caesar's crossing of the Rubicon.  And could have called in another army to follow behind.  Defense would become easier, as messages could travel much faster than armies.  So the defending forces could encounter invaders better.

Also consider how difficult it is even today to find someone.  Kidnapping would be eliminated.  Just give a messenger a message for the victim and follow.  No fugitives from justice either.  If you can identify someone, you can find that person.  Criminals would need to avoid identification at all costs.

Increasing the surety of punishment has a greater effect than increasing the severity of punishment.  It doesn't matter how tough a punishment is if you expect to be able to avoid it.  But here there is no escape from punishment once identified.  Crime would be less common in that case.

Tyrannies would be stronger and more persistent, as rebel leaders couldn't hide and build their forces.  It would be easier to redeploy forces to counter rebellions.

More stable empires with less crime might actually be bad for technological advancement.  It's better in that there wouldn't have been the long pause between the Roman empire and the Renaissance.  But there also would have been less pressure for advancement.  Who needs cannons and guns if you don't plan to fight anyone?